# Using Microsoft Graph API to Extract Microsoft Booking Data

Tags: python-3.x, azure, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-booking

I am trying to call the Microsoft Graph API, in an automated way using application permissions, to extract the Microsoft Bookings data.

The AAD app has the `Bookings.Read.All` permissions as explained here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/bookingbusiness-list?view=graph-rest-1.0

This is how I am getting a token:

```
import msal

client_id = 'x'
client_secret = 'x'
authority = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/x'
scope = ['https://graph.microsoft.com/.default']

client = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(client_id, authority=authority, client_credential=client_secret)

token_result = client.acquire_token_silent(scope, account=None)

if token_result:
  access_token = 'Bearer ' + token_result['access_token']
  print('Access token was loaded from cache')

if not token_result:
  token_result = client.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=scope)
  access_token = 'Bearer ' + token_result['access_token']
  print('New access token was acquired from Azure AD')

print(access_token)
```

This is how I am calling the Graph API. However, it returns error 500 with a message saying "An error has occurred"

```
import requests

url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/solutions/bookingBusinesses'
headers = {
  'Authorization': access_token
}

graph_result = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)

print(graph_result)
```

What is wrong here?

**Update 1**

Calling some other endpoints does work, which suggest the Python is okay, and the access token is okay. For example, if I use the `Get bookingBusiness`, instead of the `List bookingBusiness`, which is basically the company ID on the endpoint, it works and returns data. But obviously that doesn't solve the problem. So this example endpoint would work:

```
booking_business_endpoint = "/solutions/bookingBusinesses/CalendarTest@company.com"
```

**Update 2**

The AAD App permissions are configured as shown here:
[AAD Permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2Lbc.png)

**Update 3**

The solution posted below by Venkatesan works for generating an authorization code, and the code can be converted into an access token, albeit manually, however the access token doesn't work when calling the API. Error 401 is returned with this message:

```
b'{"error":{"code":"","message":"Authorization has been denied for this request.","innerError":{"date":"2023-04-12T10:35:49","request-id":"b8904cad-c994-4a91-bd61-6bfbcb87bbaa","client-request-id":"b8904cad-c994-4a91-bd61-6bfbcb87bbaa"}}}'
```

Answer (score 0):

**I tried in my environment and got the below results.**

Initially, I got the same error as got an access token with a 500 error.

```
jQeYP81SRbbh0PaBVD1ceKfyPzySsF2AArPlq8xFU-z3dZueSmHTifmEkSDcR3Cu-LZfw
b'{"error":{"code":"","message":"An error has occurred.","innerError":{"date":"2023-04-05T10:30:49","request-id":"e3f5bc5f-db7d-468d-92ef-abe33abc25c9","client-request-id":"e3f5bc5f-db7d-468d-92ef-abe33abc25c9"}}}'
500
```

[image]

The above error occurs when you tried with client credentials flow for delegated permission (Bookings.Read.All, BookingsAppointment.ReadWrite.All, Bookings.ReadWrite.All, Bookings.Manage.All).

For delegated permission, you need to use the authorization code flow process. You can use the below code to get the access token and `bookingBusiness` using Python.

**Code:**

```
import requests
from urllib.parse import urlencode

# define the OAuth 2.0 parameters
client_id = ''
client_secret = ''
redirect_uri = 'https://jwt.ms'
auth_url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize'
token_url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token'

# generate the authorization URL
auth_params = {
    'client_id': client_id,
    'redirect_uri': redirect_uri,
    'scope':'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default',
    'response_type': 'code'
}
auth_url_with_params = auth_url + '?' + urlencode(auth_params)

# display the authorization URL to the user
print('Please go to the following URL and authorize the app:')
print(auth_url_with_params)

# once the user authorizes the app, they will be redirected to the callback URL
# with an authorization code as a parameter
authorization_code = input('Enter the authorization code: ')

# exchange the authorization code for an access token
token_params = {
    'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
    'client_id': client_id,
    'client_secret': client_secret,
    'redirect_uri': redirect_uri,
    'scope':'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default',
    'code': authorization_code
}
response = requests.post(token_url, data=token_params)

# extract the access token from the response
access_token = response.json()['access_token']
print("accesstoken",access_token)

import requests

url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/solutions/bookingBusinesses'
headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token
}

graph_result = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)

print(graph_result.content)
print(graph_result.status_code)
```

**Output:**

```
b'{"@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#solutions/bookingBusinesses","value":[{"id":"FourthCoffee@Mxxxx.onmicrosoft.com","displayName":"Fourth Coffee"}]}'
200
```

[image]

**Reference:**

[List bookingBusinesses - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/bookingbusiness-list?view=graph-rest-1.0)

Comment: Can you clarify your AAD app settings, please? I have tried your code, and I am able to get an access token. But, when pasting in the access token back into Python, the API returns error 400.

Comment: Check the api permission it has necessary permission with grant admin consent like this [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/18DHxHv.png).

Comment: Can you attach a snip of the decoded access token in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms/)?

Comment: Are you trying to decode the auth-code or access token?

Comment: Returning 401 now... "message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."

Comment: Can you please elaborate with proper snips on what you are trying to do?

Comment: Updated the original post

Comment: To resolve the error make sure to grant admin consent to the [API permissions](https://i.imgur.com/R0lgZuj.png) also you need global administrator role.

Comment: I don't think we're going down the right path here because don't we need to use an application permission if this is to be fully automated? It's not fully automated if we're having to log in, then copy and paste auth codes?

Comment: According to this [MsDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/bookingbusiness-list?view=graph-rest-1.0#permissions) application permissions is not supported to achieve your scenario. Hence make use of delegated permissions and authcode flow.